# If $X$ is countable and $f(X)$ is infinite then $f(X)$ is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Intuitively, this makes sense, because if $|f(X)|$ should be less than or equal to $|X|$. And since $\mathbb{N}$ is the smallest infinity. This should make both |f(X)| and |X| equal to $|\mathbb{N}|$. I am having trouble stating this formally though.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems like the claim $|f(X)| \leq |X|$ requires some form of choice. Otherwise, your argument seems good, except that $|f(X)|$ should be less than or equal to $|\mathbb{N}|$

Comment: @leibnewtz: No choice is needed here.

Comment: @leibnewtz The fact that $|f(X)| \le |X|$ follows simply from the fact that $f$ is an onto function $X\to f(X).$ No choice. The place where choice might naively seem necessary is for showing that since $f(X)$ is infinite then $ f(X)\ge \aleph_0$ since a general claim of this form requires countable choice. But as Clive's answer shows, that's not even needed here since we have a function $\mathbb N \to f(X)$ from which we can obtain a well-ordering on $f(X).$

Comment: Ah yes of course

Answer (score 1):

Let $U \subseteq X$ with $U$ infinite and $X$ countable. We'll prove that $U$ is countable. This implies your result by letting $U=f(X)$.

---

Since $X$ is countable, there is a bijection $f : \mathbb{N} \to X$. Define a new function $g : \mathbb{N} \to U$ by letting $g(n) = f(k_n)$, where $k_n$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$-least natural number such that $f(k_n) \in U$.

Formally, you could define $g$ recursively by
$$g(n) = f(\mathrm{min} \{ k \mid f(k) \in U - \{ g(i) \mid i < n \} \})$$

Intuitively, $f$ enumerates the elements of $X$ as $\{ x_0, x_1, x_2, \dots \}$, and $g$ enumerates the elements of $U$ as $\{ x_{k_0}, x_{k_1}, x_{k_2}, \dots \}$, where the natural numbers $k_0,k_1,\dots$ are in increasing order: it enumerates the elements of $U$ by progressing element-by-element through the elements of $X$ and throwing away the ones that aren't in $U$.

It is easy to check that $g$ is a bijection: well-definedness uses the fact that $U$ is infinite, and injectivity follows from injectivity of $f$, and surjectivity follows from the recursive definition of $g$.

Hence $U$ is countable.

---

If you already know that $|\mathbb{N}|$ is the smallest infinity, then the proof is even easier. We know that $U \subseteq X$, so the function $i : U \to X$ defined by $i(u)=u$ for all $u \in U$ is injective, and so $|U|\le|X|$. Since $U$ is infinite we have $|U| \ge \mathbb{N}$ and since $X$ is countable we have $|X| \le |\mathbb{N}|$, and hence
$$|\mathbb{N}| \le |U| \le |X| \le |\mathbb{N}|$$
so that $|U|=|X|=|\mathbb{N}|$.

Answer (score 0):

This follows quite easily from the definition of a *function*.  The domain has cardinality at least as much as the image;   for there is one,  and only one,  $y $ in the image for each  $x $ in the domain...

I believe Cantor expressed it by saying that if there is a surjection from  $X $ to $Y $, then $\lvert Y\rvert \le \lvert X \rvert  $...

Answer (score 0):

For all y in f(X), $f^{-1}(y)$ is not empty.
By AxC define g:f(X) -> X, y -> some x from $f^{-1}(y)$.
g is an injection from f(X) into X.  Thus |f(X)| <= |X|.